# New Site Name and Scope Proposals: what happens to the hyperlinks?

Tags: discussion, new-site-name

I'm following more or less all the current buzz about changing the site name. I entirely agree with the proposal.

However, I haven't seen mentioned (maybe it was, but, well, there are *a lot* of answers and comments) anything about one particular technical aspect involved in the change of the site name: hyperlinks.

Imagine I have [a link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/46716/6605) in my blog, pointing to a very popular, highly upvoted question with an excellent answer. What would happen after the site is renamed and—I imagine—moved to a different third-level domain name?

- Would it be [automatically redirected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to the corresponding question on the new site?
- Would it show a page telling that the website moved, inviting the user to figure out by herself how to find the new question?
- Or would it simply result in [a generic HTTP 404](http://example.stackexchange.com/)?

In my opinion, only the first solution is a valid approach. Anything else would be disastrous both for the overall internet community (there are enough dead links already on the internet), and specifically for the newly renamed website: an important number of new users come here from Google, and it would take some time for Google to reindex all the content on the new site.

Comment: Keep in mind the domain doesn't necessarily have to change.

Comment: @enderland That's true. However, it would help with communicating the URL. Plus, there's precedent for it, with the most recent being Beer (beer.SE.com) to Beer. Wine, & Spirits (alcohol.SE.com).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Automatically redirected to the corresponding question on the new site" is correct. This is what happened in the past when sites were renamed: for example, https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/q/1 redirects to [What is a citra hop, and how does it differ from other hops?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/q/1).

Comment: Just to add... must me a 301 redirect : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en (Obviously the SE people would know this )